# Create a list of 10 most expensive products, using Sub-queries, in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

So I have done the first part of the task which as you can see by the code is to create a list of all products who's Name begins with `'BK'` but I am having trouble writing a subquery which extracts only the top ten most expensive items.

Further note, I cannot just add a `'WHERE'` to only select two values which appear in the top ten entries as the data may change

Code and image are below:

```
select [ProductID], [Name], [Color], [ListPrice]
from [Production].[Product]
where [ProductNumber] like 'BK%'
order by [ListPrice]
```

[image: Table of Products with Name Colour and ListPrice, ordered by ListPrice]

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT TOP (10)`.

Comment: your DBMS seems to be SQL-Server, because of square-bracketed format, isn't it? So use `TOP` as @GordonLinoff mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL-server.

Comment: another hint - might want to `order by ListPrice DESC` if you want the most expensive ones

Answer (score 2):

Why use a subquery? Just order the products in descending price order and take the top 10:

```
select TOP 10
[ProductID]
,[Name]
,[Color]
,[ListPrice]
from [Production].[Product]
where[ProductNumber] like 'BK%'
order by  [ListPrice] DESC
```

Comment: @StephanSpittal If that suggestion works for you, then please mark it (and any others that you find useful) as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
[ProductID]
   ,[Name]
     ,[Color]
      ,[ListPrice]

      from [Production].[Product]
  where[ProductNumber] like 'BK%'
   and LISTPRICE IN (SELECT TOP 10 DISTINCT LISTPRICE FROM   
    [Production].[Product] ORDER BY LISTPRICE DESC)
```

> But It doesnt require subquery as such to do it if you still want you can use this.

Comment: the code shows the first 13 rows, not the first 10.

    select 
    [ProductID]
    ,[Name]
    ,[ProductNumber]
    ,[Color]
    ,[ListPrice]

    from [Production].[Product]
    where [ProductNumber] like 'BK%'
    and [ListPrice] in (select top 10 [ListPrice]
  from [Production].[Product]
  order by [ListPrice] desc)

Answer (score 0):

You already have your filtered data. Just turn that into the subquery, and select the TOP 10 from there.

```
WITH TEMP_TABLE AS (
    select 
    [ProductID]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Color]
    ,[ListPrice]

    from [Production].[Product]
    where[ProductNumber] like 'BK%')
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TEMP_TABLE ORDER BY [ListPrice] DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() function to generate unique IDs for each row of the record-set. Then finally filter out records ranging from 0 to 10.
Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) link to learn about ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja have a look at the question before asking something. why data won't be sorted as desc?